# Spring AMQP - Message re queuing using dead letter mechanism with TTL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Its like "**Houston we have a problem here**" where I need to schedule/delay a message for 5 minutes after it fails on the first attempt to process an event.
I have implemented dead letter exchange in this scenario.

The messages on failing, route to the DLX --> Retry Queue and comes back to work queue after a TTL of 5 minutes for another attempt.

Here is the configuration I am using:

```
public class RabbitMQConfig {
    @Bean(name = "work")
    @Primary
    Queue workQueue() {
        return new Queue(WORK_QUEUE, true, false, false, null);
    }

    @Bean(name = "workExchange")
    @Primary
    TopicExchange workExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(WORK_EXCHANGE, true, false);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding workBinding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(workQueue()).to(workExchange()).with("#");
    }

    @Bean(name = "retryExchange")
    FanoutExchange retryExchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange(RETRY_EXCHANGE, true, false);
    }

    @Bean(name = "retry")
    Queue retryQueue() {
        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", WORK_EXCHANGE);
        args.put("x-message-ttl", RETRY_DELAY); //delay of 5 min
        return new Queue(RETRY_QUEUE, true, false, false, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding retryBinding(Queue queue,FanoutExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(retryQueue()).to(retryExchange());
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    Consumer receiver() {
        return new Consumer();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Consumer receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }
}
```

Producer.java:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/hello")
public String sayHello() {
    // Producer operation

        String messages[];
        messages = new String[] {" hello "};

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String message = util.getMessage(messages)+i;

        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("WorkExchange","", message);
       System.out.println(" Sent '" + message + "'");
    }
    return "hello";
}
```

Consumer.java:

```
public class Consumer {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "WorkQueue")
    public void receiveMessage(String message, Channel channel,
            @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long tag) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        try {

            System.out.println("message to be processed: " + message);
            doWorkTwo(message);
            channel.basicAck(tag, false);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("In the exception catch block");
            System.out.println("message in dead letter exchange: " + message);
            channel.basicPublish("RetryExchange", "", null, message.getBytes());

        }

    }

    private void doWorkTwo(String task) throws InterruptedException {

        int c = 0;
        int b = 5;
        int d = b / c;

    }

}
```

Is it the correct way to use a dead letter exchange for my scenario and **after waiting once in the RETRY QUEUE for 5 min, on the second time attempt it does not wait for 5 min in the RETRY QUEUE (I have mentioned TTL as 5 min) and moves to the WORK QUEUE immediately**.

I am running this application by hitting localhost:8080/hello url.

***Here is my updated configuration.***

RabbitMQConfig.java:

```
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    final static String WORK_QUEUE = "WorkQueue";
    final static String RETRY_QUEUE = "RetryQueue";
    final static String WORK_EXCHANGE = "WorkExchange"; // Dead Letter Exchange
    final static String RETRY_EXCHANGE = "RetryExchange";
    final static int RETRY_DELAY = 60000; // in ms (1 min)

    @Bean(name = "work")
    @Primary
    Queue workQueue() {
         Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", RETRY_EXCHANGE);
        return new Queue(WORK_QUEUE, true, false, false, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "workExchange")
    @Primary
    DirectExchange workExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(WORK_EXCHANGE, true, false);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding workBinding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(workQueue()).to(workExchange()).with("");
    }

    @Bean(name = "retryExchange")
    DirectExchange retryExchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(RETRY_EXCHANGE, true, false);
    }

    // Messages will drop off RetryQueue into WorkExchange for re-processing
    // All messages in queue will expire at same rate
    @Bean(name = "retry")
    Queue retryQueue() {
        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        //args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", WORK_EXCHANGE);
        //args.put("x-message-ttl", RETRY_DELAY);
        return new Queue(RETRY_QUEUE, true, false, false, null);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding retryBinding(Queue queue, DirectExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(retryQueue()).to(retryExchange()).with("");
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
        /*factory.setAdviceChain(new Advice[] {
                org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.RetryInterceptorBuilder
                        .stateless()
                        .maxAttempts(2).recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())
                        .backOffOptions(1000, 2, 5000)
                        .build()
        });*/
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    Consumer receiver() {
        return new Consumer();
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Consumer receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }
}
```

Consumer.java:

```
public class Consumer {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "WorkQueue")
    public void receiveMessage(String message, Channel channel,
            @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long tag,
            @Header(required = false, name = "x-death") HashMap<String, String> xDeath)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        doWorkTwo(message);
        channel.basicAck(tag, false);
    }

    private void doWorkTwo(String task) {
        int c = 0;
        int b = 5;
        if (c < b) {
            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(task);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are suggesting doesn't make any sense - since you are publishing to the retry queue yourself, the broker has no knowledge that this is a second retry - it's just a new message from its perspective - so won't take any different action.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell . How can I accomplish the scenario where the broker can acknowledge that its a second retry and so on. I have tried several things but always get the count as 1.
How can the publish to the retryQueue happen automatically?

Comment: If you reject and requeue directly, the broker only has an indication that it is redelivered, not a count; if you reject to a DLQ then the broker keeps count via the `x-death` header - see my answer. If you publish it yourself to the DLQ, you need to keep count via your own header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reject the message so the broker routes it to a DLQ, you can examine the `x-death` header. In this scenario, I have a DLQ with a TTL of 5 seconds and the consumer of the message from the main queue rejects it; the broker routes it to the DLQ, then it expires and is routed back to the main queue - the `x-death` header shows the number of re-routing operations:

[image: x-death header]

Comment: how do I reject the message to go to the DLQ?
Using channel.reject will simply remove the message from the workQueue itself . Do I need to handle it differently in the catch block? or is my configuration file has something missing?

Comment: You have to configure the queue with an `x-dead-letter-exchange` argument and bind your DLQ to that exchange with the proper routing key (if the exchange type requires one - or use a fanout exchange and bind the queue to it). See [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html).

Comment: @GaryRusselI, I added factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false); to the SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory Bean ,still the failed messages do not come to the DLQ(retryQueue). What am I missing on to reject a message so that it goes directly to the DLQ?

Comment: ,I have already configured the queue with `x-dead-letter-exchange` and a `x-message-ttl` in the above present RabbitMQconfig file.. I am using a fanout exchange so I am not using any routing key. Can you please help me where I am wrong with my configurations. Thanks

Comment: You need to show your current configuration - the configuration in your question has you catching the exception and manually publishing; the message will be ack'd normally in that case. You need to throw an exception if you want the container to reject the message; `defaultRequeueRejected=false` has no effect unless you throw an exception.

Comment: ,Thanks for the help. I have added my latest configurations above. I am able to send the rejected message to the retryExchange now. But once the messages go into that retryQueue they will not come back to the workQueue for another round of processing. **Do I need to set the workExchange as the DLX for reteyQueue now?** So that after my messages are dead lettered, they can come back for another round of processing.

Comment: Yes, the retry queue has to be configured with dead-lettering to route the expired message back to the original queue.