# Spring RabbitMQ - Message Requeue limit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Using Spring-boot and Spring-starter-amqp for my messaging app. My Problem scenario is this :

**First Problem** : I want to requeue my message only for 5 times and then message should be comeout from queue if business exception occurs(here I am focusing only on business exception).

**Second Problem** : If first use case is possible, can we somehow increase time to requeue based on the attempts. Suppose in the first attempt business exception occurs it should requeue immediately but in the second attempt it should requeue after 2 mins then 4 mins then 6 mins then 8 mins then 10 mins like time will increase based on the attempt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the simple case (fixed delay between attempts), you can configure the queue to send rejected messages a dead letter exchange, and throw `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`.

Bind a queue to the dead letter exchange, and set a time to live (ttl) on that queue and also configure it with a dead letter exchange to which the original queue is bound. The message will be requeued after the TTL expires.

You would need to examine the `x-death` header to determine how many times around the loop the message has traversed. After your retries are exhausted, throw an `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException` to discard the message.

For a variable delay, you have to republish the message yourself, to a delayed-message exchange (there's a broker plugin for that), with the delay increasing for each retry.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258684/spring-amqp-message-re-queuing-using-dead-letter-mechanism-with-ttl/41536288#41536288).

Comment: don"t want to use broker plugin for that; Can we do this using custom interceptor something ?

Comment: No; for a variable delay you will either have to use the delayed message exchange plugin or publish the message yourself to the DLQ instead of rejecting it. You can use `RabbitTemplate.send(message)`) with `messageProperties.setExpiration()` See [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) - Spring AMQP will map the expiration property for you.

Comment: if I send message using RabbitTemplate.send(message)) with messageProperties.setExpiration() for delayed message timeout. How can I count the no's of failed attempt due consumer's business exception

Comment: You need to set a custom header e.g. "deliveryAttempts". Add it the first time, set to 1, and increment it thereafter.